# In PHP, how does 'assign by reference' work with this new stdclass?

Tags: php

This page of the PHP Manual says that only a named variable can be assigned by reference, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php.  It gives the example that `$bar = &$foo;` is a valid assignment, but `$bar = &(24 * 7);` is not.

In the page on variable scope however, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php, it gives an example of `$obj = &new stdclass;`.

How can this be so?  `new stdclass` is not a named variable!

Thanks...

Comment: in PHP5, the use of `&` is not necessary anymore. it is only preserved for backwards compatibility. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490836/php-returning-references-necessary-in-caller

Comment: Very important here is that that is only the case of **objects**, 'regular' variables (numbers, strings, arrays), are not passed by reference by default, only objects are.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` construct is a little special with references:

```
$obj = &new stdclass;
```

Actually it's not recommended to do this any longer (that's PHP 4 code), you should write it as such:

```
$obj = new stdclass;
```

However for the sake of the argument and your question, there is also [return by reference<sup>*shy;Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) which is passing the said *named variable* as the return value of a function:

```
$obj = &someFunction();
```

As you can imagine, this could work with other language constructs as well. The important point is, if there is a reference, there must be some variable. Without a variable you can't have a reference in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little explained here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

"The same syntax can be used with functions that return references, and with the new operator (since PHP 4.0.4 and before PHP 5.0.0):"